# Intuition behind a random variable being a measurable function with a specific example.

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I'm just starting to learn measure theory and we have defined a random variable $X$ as a measurable function from some set $\Omega$ to some other set $E$ which is usually $\mathbb{R}$. We defined $\mathbb{P}(X \in S)$ for $S$ measurable in $E$ as being $\mu(\{\omega: X(\omega) \in S\})$ where $\mu$ is the probability measure on $\Omega$.

I'm struggling to understand how this relates to the "usual" pre-measure theory definition of a random variable. For example if we had a standard Gaussian R.V what would $\Omega$ be and what would the map $X$ be?

My intuitions tell me we should take $\Omega$ to be $(0,1)$ with the standard measure and then $X$ sends $\omega \in \Omega$ to $\inf\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x: \omega \leq F(x)\}$ where $F$ is the C.D.F of the Gaussian. However I found a very similar question on this site which said we take $\Omega$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ as the identity map which didn't really make sense to me.

Any clarifications are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not generally a 'right answer' for what probability space to take in order to support some particular random variable. I think the probability space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R), P)$ where $$P(A) = \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx,$$ where we take $X$ to be the identity function on $\mathbb R,$ is a fine choice.

Your choice works just fine as well. The only important thing is that for any $x\in \mathbb R,$ $$\mu(\{\omega\in \Omega :X(\omega)\le x\}) = \int_{-\infty}^x  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx.$$

The first example I gave (which is presumably the same one in the other post) is a special probability space called the *law* of $X.$ It is given abstractly in terms of *any* underlying probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ with $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ as$$ P(A) = \mu(X^{-1}(A))$$ for any Borel-measureable $A\subseteq R.$ In other words, it is the [push-forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $\mu$ by the $\Sigma-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function $X.$

Comment: So in this case is the $\sigma$-algebra on the preimage still the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan You mean in this specific example $\Omega=(0,1)$ what is the 'standard'? Borel as opposed to the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, I thought we usually used the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for all these calculations. Just learned about the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and now I'm confused as I thought they were both the same (i.e. every measurable set is Borel).

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan Yes, the standard choice for the probability space you suggest would be $((0,1),\mathcal B((0,1)), \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal B((0,1))$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(0,1).$ This makes sense since every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable (but not the other way around). If you chose the full Lebesgue algebra $\mathcal L((0,1))$ instead, it would not make any difference here, since $X$ is $\mathcal B(0,1) -\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable, so it is $\mathcal L(0,1)-\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable (again, because $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal L$).

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan Actually I could have just called $\mu$ Borel measure rather than Lebesgue since the Borel measure is just the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to $\mathcal B.$ But again, extending the probability space to the Lebesgue algebra and Lebesgue measure is unnecessary but not harmful here.